# Forcing brightness increase

Tags: drivers, video, brightness

I'm a desktop user, and since my LCD screen died I have to use an old CRT screen that has some issues. I set its both contrast and brightess settings to 100%, but there's some stuff I still couldn't see very well on screen, because it's way too obscure.

It seems like there are ways to increse the bright by software side, but, maybe because this computer happens to not be a laptop itself, those are all disabled. Is there any way to force those options to be enabled no matter ANY condition, so I can force my stuff to look more lightful? I don't mind the image's quality loss.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... probably @A.B. is right. But I had a CRT where the problem was really the gamma (the curve applied to the luminosity to make it linear to the eye). You can try to play with the curve values. So:

1. Find the name of your device:

   ```
   [romano:~] % xrandr --current
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
   VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
      1920x1080      60.0*+
      1680x1050      60.0  
      1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
      1152x864       75.0  
      1024x768       75.1     60.0  
      800x600        75.0     60.3  
      640x480        75.0     60.0  
      720x400        70.1  
   HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```
2. it's `VGA1` for me... play with this command:

   ```
   [romano:~] % xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 1.5
   ```
3. if this is a mess (in my LCD all goes mostly white ;-) --- can't show with a screenshot because the shot is ok --- pixels are still the same), go back with

   ```
   [romano:~] % xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 1.0
   ```

(It is not a bad idea to have it ready on another terminal so that  you can execute it blindly). You can also have a look at `--gamma` for finer control. From `xrandr` manual:

> ```
>    --gamma red:green:blue
>           Set the specified floating point values as gamma  correction  on
>           the crtc currently attached to this output. Note that you cannot
>           get two different values for cloned outputs (i.e.:  which  share
>           the  same  crtc)  and  that  switching an output to another crtc
>           doesn't change the crtc gamma corrections at all.
>
>    --brightness brightness
>           Multiply the gamma values on the crtc currently attached to  the
>           output  to specified floating value. Useful for overly bright or
>           overly dim outputs.  However, this is a software only  modifica‐
>           tion,  if  your  hardware  has  support  to  actually change the
>           brightness, you will probably prefer to use xbacklight.
> ```

Default values *probably* are `--gamma 1.0:1.0:1.0 --brightness 1.0`, but you can check with `xrandr --verbose`.

Comment: Marvelous. This is the only solution that has worked!, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CRT monitors tend to lose their luminosity as they get older. You should buy a new monitor. Alternatively, you could use a theme for your GUI with a high contrast.

Comment: Ugh. Just why am I not allowed to increase the brightness like in here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2tOYJ01uFw

Comment: Because a CRT is a analogue device?

Comment: It seems like my CRT screen does "crush the blacks", as white colors still seem well enough. Software-based bright add seems to be a good enough workaround here. All I want is to enable this software-based bright add (which is why the guy in the video can set individual brightness settings for each window).

Comment: Try another cable first. I will watch the video later.

Comment: I can't watch the video in my country :\

Comment: Then have a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Is76wQI.png
A different cable makes no difference. And CompizConfig doesn't allow me those brigthness settings

Comment: That are settings for Unity/Compiz right. But I believe, that doesn't works with old analogue CRT monitors.

Comment: Try this answer http://superuser.com/q/256084/427428